# How can I enrich Serilog with ServiceBus.Message.CorrelationId

Tags: serilog

I want to Enrich Serilog properties with the value of the `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message.CorrelationId` property in the following Azure Function.

```cs
public static class Function2
{
    [FunctionName("Function2")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("test-pm")]Message myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

So far I am able to Enrich my logger with my own ILogEventEnricher and the code is executed as expected every time I log. Not only does this not work, but I don't think it is the correct approach at all.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(AzureStuff.MyStartup))]
namespace AzureStuff
{

    public class MyStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.With<MyEnricher>()
                .WriteTo.Debug()
                .CreateLogger();
        }
    }

    public class MyEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
    {
        public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But I am unable to inject `FunctionExecutingContext` into the constructor of `MyEnricher` because `Enrich.With<TEnricher>` has a `new()` constraint on the generic.